# How to pull Facebook comments and feeds to hadoop?

Tags: facebook, hadoop

I am working on a case study where I have to get comments, activities etc. from my facebook page and aggregate them in Hadoop for textual analysis using map reduce.

What is the right way to pull Facebook fan page Feeds? Is there any API for it, which can be consumed by hadoop components like flume or scribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the JSON API is called [Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), I recommend you start with the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)